# Query repeated multiple times in a many-to-many relation

Tags: django, django-models, orm, django-admin

I have a problem with a many to many relationship in Django Admin.

I have simplified my model so that it does not contain irrelevant fields for the problem.

If we take "actor" as an example. If I have, for example, 15 actors for a movie, SQL makes 15 queries instead of one.

I have search for a long time now but only finds solutuions for one to many based on the foreignkey thats automaticly created in my "many to many" relation.

### I am grateful for any help I can get!

### models.py

```
class Cast(models.Model):
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        indexes = [["firstname", "lastname"]]
        
    class Meta:
        abstract= True

class Director(Cast):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.firstname + ' ' + self.lastname

class Actor(Cast):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.firstname + ' ' + self.lastname            

class Film(models.Model):
    title_eng = models.CharField(max_length=250, verbose_name='Title English')

    directors = models.ManyToManyField(Director, related_name='directors')
    actors = models.ManyToManyField(Actor, related_name='actors')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title_eng
```

### admin_film.py

```
class DirectorInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Director.directors.through
    verbose_name_plural = "Film-Director"
    list_display = ['firstname','lastname']
    extra = 0

@admin.register(Director)
class DirectorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ("firstname",)
    list_display = ['id', 'firstname', 'lastname', 'get_fullname']
    fields = ['firstname', 'lastname', 'fullname']

    def get_fullname(self, obj):
        fullname = ""
        if (len(obj.firstname) != 0):
            fullname = obj.firstname
        return fullname

class ActorInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Actor.actors.through
    verbose_name_plural = "Film-Actor"
    classes = ('collapse',)
    extra = 0

@admin.register(Actor)
class ActorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ("firstname__startswith", )
    list_display = ['id', 'firstname', 'lastname']
    fields = ['firstname', 'lastname', 'fullname']
    
@admin.register(Film)
class FilmAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ('title_eng')
    list_display = ['id', 'title_eng']
    list_display_links  = ['id', 'title_eng']
    fields = ['title_eng']
    ordering = ['title_eng']
    inlines = [DirectorInline, ActorInline]
```